# Page 7 of WordPress pagination redirects back to home

Tags: wordpress, redirect, pagination, themes, genesis

I'm using Genesis Framework for my site and running into a weird issue. The pagination is working fine except the 7th page. The 7th page of the pagination bar redirects back to the home automatically.

Here's the link to the [7th page](https://www.digitalkube.com/page/7/).

Other links in the pagination are working perfectly but not sure what's wrong with page 7. I tried switching to "Next-Prev" pagination but the same is happening. As soon as you reach the 7th page, it redirects back to home again.

Why is it happening? Please help!

Comment: It is because of some cache plugin or server cache. f.e. test this: https://digitalkube.com/page/7/?Ds=ds  it would work OK. it means there is some cache issue. try to clean all possible caches you now. (plugins, Varnish, Cloudflare etc.)

Comment: Memcached on my server was causing it and I don't know why. Flushed all the cache, updated permalinks settings and it started to work perfectly. I'm not sure why it happened because as far as I know, it was working fine till yesterday. Thanks, @ElvinHaci for the instant fix :)